# File redirection not working if I SetCurrentDirectory to C:\Program Files in 32 bit app on Win7 64 bit, should it not navigate to (x86) folder?

Tags: c++, winapi, 64-bit

Here is my test code below.

```
//This correctly prints C:\Program Files from 64 app on 64 bit Win7 and
//C:\Program Files (x86) 32 bit app on 64 bit Win7
system("echo %PROGRAMFILES%\n");

BOOL ret = SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\");

char szFolder[512] = {0};
GetCurrentDirectory(512, szFolder);

//folder is printed as C:\Program Files from 32 bit app on 64 Win7! Why?
cout << "Current folder now: " << szFolder << endl;
```

Reason for writing code is to test what would happen if 32 bit InstallShield set path to C:\Program Files.  We want the path to be set to C:\Program Files on 32 bit OS and C:\Program Files (x86) on 64 bit OS.  I assumed that the Windows File System Redirection feature would ensure this happened?

Basically, we have to locate a 32 bit library which will be in (x86) folder.  We were hoping that setting to C:\Program Files would be redirected correctly so we don't have to worry about it?

Why is SetCurrentDirectory not being redirected?  I am testing on 64 bit Windows 7.  Application is compiled using MS VSC++ 2008.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite simple. The `Program Files` directory is not subject to [file redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You probably would be best using the `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILES` and `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86` [CSIDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762494%28VS.85%29.aspx) values but you'll have to work out for yourself whether you need the x64 or x86 folders.

Comment: It only relates to System32 folder?